# Large JSON URL loading too slowly in LeafLet JS Map

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

Warning: novice here

I am building a real estate website in PHP.  I am now adding a map view via LeafLetJs which is all JavaScript.  I have my map setup and all properties are coming in correctly.  My issue is that the page takes about 17 seconds to load.  It only loads around 500 properties instead of the 2000 being supplied in the json url.  I believe it is timing out as the json data is pretty large (30mb).

What is the proper way to populate a map quickly?  Here is my code:

```
var url =
  "https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData/actris/Property/replication?access_token=(TokenHere)&$top=2000";
var map = L.map("map", { tap: false }).setView([30.26, -97.74], 11);
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    error: function () {
      console.log("JSON FAILED for data");
    },
    success: function (results) {
      const numberFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
        style: "currency",
        currency: "USD",
        minimumFractionDigits: 0,
      });
      var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
      var cartItemsList = document.getElementById("cartItemsList");
      results.value.forEach(function (element) {
        //cartItemsList.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend',"<li>" + element.UnparsedAddress + " : " + element.Longitude+ " : " + element.Latitude+ " </li>");
        var marker = L.marker([element.Latitude, element.Longitude]).bindPopup(
          '<a href="property.php?id=' + element.ListingId +
            '"><div class="card"><img class="card-img-top" src="' + element.Media[0].MediaURL +
            '" style="height:160px;max-height:160px;object-fit: scale-down;"><div class="d-inline-flex p-2 justify-content-between align-items-start"><div class="rp-1 bd-highlight">' +
            element.StreetNumber + " " + element.StreetName + " " +
            element.StreetSuffix + "<br>" + element.City + ", " +
            element.StateOrProvince + " " + element.PostalCode +
            '</div><div class="lp-1 bd-highlight" style="text-align: right;">' +
            numberFormatter.format(element.ListPrice) +
            " <br> ID " + element.ListingId +
            "</div></div></div></a>"
        );
        markers.addLayer(marker);
        map.addLayer(markers);
      }); // end of forEach
    }, // end of success fn
  }); // end of Ajax call
}); // end of $(document).ready() function

L.tileLayer(
  "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=my_mapbox_access_token",
  {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution:
      'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
      'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: "mapbox/streets-v11",
  }
).addTo(map);

markers.addLayer(marker);
map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());
```

Comment: The code you show clearly seems incomplete, especially in the success callback part, which could help make sure your issue does not come from there. And how did you check that you actually receive 2000 features, and that you display only 500?

Comment: Hello, didn’t think about the token. I removed it and got a new one. I can load the json data in a webpage and see it has 2,000 results included. It’s capped at that per the issuers rules. I use clusters on my map and can see the total markers are 493.  I believe it’s stopping there because there’s a timeout rule in Leaflet.

Comment: Also...I only included the connection part of my code.  I have now updated it to include the entire page.  Only thing missing is the header.

Comment: I suggest diving deeper into what's taking up those 17 seconds. Start by reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thanks for the tip.  ghybs's answer seems to have cleared up the time issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably there are 2 performance bottlenecks:

1. When loading 30MB of data, I would expect it takes a few seconds on most connections. But it is strangely heavy just for 2,000 features.
2. When adding a lot of Markers into MarkerClusterGroup, if you do so individually and the MCG is on the map, it will perform a lot of computations, delaying rendering by several seconds. Use [`addLayers` method](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#bulk-adding-and-removing-markers) (note the **s** at the end) once with an array of all your Markers:

> Bulk adding and removing Markers
>
> `addLayers` and `removeLayers` are bulk methods for adding and removing markers and should be favoured over the single versions when doing bulk addition/removal of markers. Each takes an array of markers.

In your case it could be something like: (in your success callback)

```js
const arrayOfMarkers = results.value.map(element => 
  L.marker([element.Latitude, element.Longitude]).bindPopup(/* etc. */)
);
const mcg = L.markerClusterGroup();
mcg.addLayers(arrayOfMarkers);
mcg.addTo(map);
```

As for the discrepancy between the number of displayed features, it *might* be due to the computation delay, but I rather suspect you may not receive as many features as you think: simply log `results.value.length` to make sure.

Comment: This has helped a ton!  I seem to still have a bit of an issue however.

Comment: If I keep my popups the way they are and include photos for each of them they take about 3 seconds to load in but if I try to load more than 465 nothing at all will load...no markers or clusters.

If I remove the photos I am not able to load all 2000 markers.

Comment: I'm curious if it would make sense for me to try and only load the visible map and not the entire 2000 json results.  I keep trying to find information on how to do this and I'm not getting anywhere.  Is this something that can be done?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am not sure I follow your comments, sorry (especially the part "_If I remove the photos I am not able to load all 2000 markers_"). It _might_ be better suited as a new question, with more details on that popup issue. If possible, provide a reproduction example. It is also strange that your service sends heavy pictures in the listing, instead of separating the list from per feature heavy details.

Comment: I created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67068078/leaflet-cant-load-all-markers-how-to-load-just-the-visible-portion-of-the-map

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the json URL was taking too much time to load.  I was able to use a select rule and only pull back the fields I needed.  Now the map loads 2000 results in just a few seconds.