# How to load only visible markers in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am connecting to a json url to pull back properties onto the Leaflet map.  There's about 2,000 coming in as markers (using Marker Cluster as well).  Each marker has a popup with an address and photo.

Problem: If I try to load all 2,000 markers with photos in the popup nothing loads at all.  I found that if I lower the number to just below 500 markers the markers can load in correctly and takes about 3 seconds to populate.  If I remove the photo from the popup the 2,000 markers will load but will take almost 20 seconds to populate.

My guess for a solution:  I'm assuming I need to use a plugin that will only load markers for the portion of the map that is visible.  When the user drags the map, or zooms out, then a request would be sent to load in for the newly visible portion of the map.

My guess is just a guess.  I have no clue if there is something a lot easier to just load everything at once.  I can't find any information on how to load just the visible portion of the map so I am not able to test this.  Any advice!!!?!!!

MY CODE:

```
var url = "https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData/actris/Property/replication?access_token=HIDDEN&$filter=MlsStatus%20eq%20%27Active%27%20and%20PropertyType%20eq%20%27Residential%27&$top=2000";
var map = L.map('map', {tap: false}).setView([30.26, -97.74], 14);
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
      error: function(){
        console.log('JSON FAILED for data');
      },
    success:function(results){
        const numberFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
   minimumFractionDigits: 0
})
<!-- <img src='+ element.Media[0].MediaURL+' class="card-img-top" style="height:160px;max-height:160px;object-fit:scale-down;"> -->
     
      const arrayOfMarkers = results.value.map(element => L.marker([element.Latitude, element.Longitude]).bindPopup('<a href="property.php?id='+element.ListingId+'"><div class="card"><div class="d-inline-flex p-2 justify-content-between align-items-start"><div class="rp-1 bd-highlight">'+element.StreetNumber + " " + element.StreetName+" " + element.StreetSuffix+ "<br>" +element.City+', '+element.StateOrProvince+' '+element.PostalCode+'</div><div class="lp-1 bd-highlight" style="text-align: right;">'+numberFormatter.format(element.ListPrice)+ " <br> ID " + element.ListingId+'</div></div></div></a>'));

const mcg = L.markerClusterGroup();
mcg.addLayers(arrayOfMarkers);
mcg.addTo(map);
  
    }  // end of success fn
   }) // end of Ajax call
 }) // end of $(document).ready() function

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3):

What you think is correct. It would be a nice idea to request only the points that will be visible. Of course, this requires server-side work as well (e.g. setting a **WFS service** in GeoServer or a **custom API** that will response with points inside your bounding box).

With this solution, you have to listen to `'moveend'` event, to get the Bounding Box, each time your map moves (zoom / pan).

```
map.on('moveend', () => {
    const bounds = map.getBounds().toBBoxString();
    /* now send your bounds to the server, requesting only the visible markers */
})
```

Another solution would be to use a **WMS service** (serving your points as tiles), in combination with the WMS `GetFeatureInfo` method for being able to fetch information by clicking on them. Again, server-side work is required (e.g. setting a GeoServer).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I couldn't get your code to work but was able to use `map.on('moveend', () => {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
 console.log(bounds);
var min = bounds.getSouthWest();
var max = bounds.getNorthEast();
})`

My json (not geoJSON) url contains Long and Lat but I can't build a search parameter around it. I'm wondering if there's a way to pull back zip codes within the bounding box as I can easily create a filter to only display zip codes.